# Parse local json with ajax, the best way

Tags: json, ajax

I'm a newbie about Ajax but I'm trying to do this:
I've got a local Json file and I have to do some Ajax calls to read the Json file and insert the values in the HTML file. My Json file is:

```
{
    "item": {
        "name": "blabla",
        "details": "blablablabla",
        "composition": "blablablabla",
        "modelDetails": [
            "blablablabla",
            "blablablabla",
            "blablablabla"
        ],
        "images": [
        "http://...jpg",
        "http://...jpg",
        "http://...jpg",
        "http://...jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this? I would like that pushing the button number one will call the first json file, with button two the second json file,...
Thank you

Edit:
The links are very usefull! Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying you want to access a file that stored locally on the client? Please provide more information. If you just want to get started with Ajax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Question is too vague. @FelixKling I think he meant local as on the server (ie where the page is stored, so relative links should be fine). However we still don't know which libraries do you intend to use, for example. Also, you could show us what you've already tried.

Comment: I haven't already tried because I'm looking for the best practice in this cases :-) Now I take a look at the links posted, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice example of ajax call to retreive JSON data from file and parse JSON data. Hope it helps :) 
http://code.runnable.com/UhY_jE3QH-IlAAAP/how-to-parse-a-json-file-using-jquery

IF link doesnt work :) Then try this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        //after button is clicked we download the data
        $('.button').click(function(){

            //start ajax request
            $.ajax({
                url: "data.json",
                //force to handle it as text
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {

                    //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function 
                    //and pass downloaded data
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    //now json variable contains data in json format
                    //Now you can get your data like json.name, json.object
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: If the linked page becomes unavailable your answer is useless. Answers should be self-contained!